# VBA, Move the cursor to the begining of the page in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, visual-studio, ms-word

How to move the cursor to the beginning of the page? Using VBA Macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the selection to the beginning of the current page using the following workaround (assuming you are starting from a collapsed selection):

```
If Selection.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) = 1 Then
    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToNext
    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
Else
    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToPrevious
    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToNext
End If
```